# Change the animation speed via script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public class door : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider obj)
    {
        var thedoor = GameObject.FindWithTag("SF_Door");

        Animation anim;
        anim = thedoor.GetComponent<Animation>();
        anim["open"].speed = 10;

        thedoor.GetComponent<Animation>().Play("open");
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider obj)
    {
        var thedoor = GameObject.FindWithTag("SF_Door");
        thedoor.GetComponent< Animation > ().Play("close");
    }
}
```

I tried to add this part:

```
Animation anim;
anim = thedoor.GetComponent<Animation>();
anim["open"].speed = 10;
```

I want to make the door open faster but the code above wasn't changing the speed.
Is there any way to do it by script without changing/adding things in the Animator/Animation windows in the editor?

Comment: Before you go too far with this code, you should be using the `Animator` component instead of the `Animation` component to play animation.   `Animation` component will be removed anytime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all - you need to stop using Animation. Instead use Mecanim with it's Animator component. Here's a decent introduction [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7RtRiniiW0c).

The easiest way is to add a new `float` parameter in your `AnimatorController` - let's call it `speedMultiplier`, then in your `AnimatorController` select the animation that you want to speed up and set it like this:

[image]

Now instead of doing `anim["open"].speed = ...` just do:

```
Animator anim = thedoor.GetComponent<Animator>();
anim.SetFloat("speedMultiplier", 10);
```

This way the animation speed will be multiplied by whatever value you set for `speedMultiplier`.

Comment: The problem is that the object the door in the Hierarchy don't have Animator component attached at all only Animation component. It's not my Prefab. Also in the Prefab it self in the Project there is no Animator component. That's why i used the Animation component in the script.

Comment: Just replace the Animation with Animator and create an AnimatorController for it.

Answer (score 1):

Add ".0f" because its a float.

```
anim["open"].speed = 10.0f;
```